# iOS14 widget didnt change dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios14

I want to change the background font style of the ios14 widget

Here is my code

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    
    //Steps
    let SteGroupName : String = "group.com.ColorWidget.SmartTimeWidget"
    
    let strStyle = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: SteGroupName)?.value(forKey: "NumberOfStyle_APP") as? String ?? "1"
    let strBatteryShowOrNot = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: SteGroupName)?.value(forKey: "isBatteryShow_APP") as? String ?? "YES"
}
```

for the first time widget changes reflect perfectly but for the rest of the time the widget not update with latest change.

Please any help appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, whenever you updated your App Group UserDefaults at the containing app, you need to call

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() // Or reloadTimelines(ofKind)
```

**at your containing app side** when it enters background (or other scenarios as you wish).

Then the Widget Extension will reload the timeline by calling `getTimeline()`.